# Get user input and then write input to python file in specific area

Tags: python, file-writing

I'm making a terminal-like program and I'm wanting a simple way for developers to add a command easily. The way I have it right now is that I have them input a name, code for the command then that code gets written to the file. Currently the command is being placed at the end of the file, doing nothing. Is there a way to place the code in a certain area or should I use a different system entirely?

Current Code:

```py
            if triggered = True:
               
                #get input
                cmd_name = input("name of command: ")
                cmd_formatting = "elif t1 == '"+cmd_name+"': "
                injected_code = input("paste command code: ")
                
                #write to the file
                f = open("app.py", "a")
                f.write(cmd_formatting+injected_code)
                print("command created succesfully ["+cmd_name+"]")
                f.close()
```

Comment: If you want to modify the contents of a file, you have to read it into a variable, modify the content and finally rewrite the file.

Comment: If there is a specific position in the pre-existing file, you could place a distinctive wildcard in the file which is then replace by the user's comment